# SQL to retrieve a list of records that are missing records in another table based on a date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

Searched high and low without luck to find an effective SQL that will allow me to find missing records in another table based on a date that is not in a given date range.

TABLE: **subscriptions**

```
+------------+
| id | label |
+------------+
| 1  | aaa   |
+------------+
| 2  | bbb   |
+------------+
| 3  | ccc   |
+------------+
| 4  | ddd   |
+------------+
```

TABLE: **subscription_periods**

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| id | subscription_id | start_at   | end_at     |
+------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 1               | 2015-12-01 | 2016-01-01 |
+------------------------------------------------+
| 2  | 1               | 2016-01-01 | 2016-02-01 |
+------------------------------------------------+ 
| 3  | 2               | 2015-12-01 | 2016-01-01 |
+------------------------------------------------+
| 4  | 3               | 2016-02-01 | 2016-03-01 |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

GOAL: Say, today is **2016-01-15** and I want to find records of `subscriptions` that are missing a `subscription_periods` record that does not have today covered based on a given date range (`subscription_periods.start_at` and `subscription_periods.end_at`).

Based on the above data, `subscriptions.id #2, #3 and #4` does not have a `subscription_periods` record that covers **2016-01-15** based on a given date range so the expected results would look like this:

```
+------------+
| id | label |
+------------+
| 2  | bbb   |
+------------+
| 3  | ccc   |
+------------+
| 4  | ddd   |
+------------+
```

Any tips are greatly appreciated and so will anybody who stumble into this issue as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will return the subscription missing in the subscription_periods for the specific date

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.id, S.label
FROM subscriptions AS S
    LEFT JOIN subscription_periods AS SP 
    ON S.id = SP.subscriptions_id AND @yourDateHere BETWEEN start_at AND end_at
WHERE SP.id IS NULL
```